# Why can't I compare two integers of different types?

Tags: rust, comparison

```
let x: i32 = 4;
let y: i16 = 4;

println!("{}", x == y);
```

When compiling the snippet above, the compiler prints the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:25
  |
5 |     println!("{}", x == y);
  |                         ^ expected i32, found i16
```

It seems that `PartialEq` is not implemented for different types of integers. The same happens between `f32` and `f64`, and for `PartialOrd` as well. Is there a reason for that? Is it intended to be implemented in future versions of Rust?

Comment: If you are keen on doing this, you could write functions and publish a crate with such logic. Looking at `PartialEq` it seems to me that you cannot implement that trait for differing types due to `RHS=Self`

Comment: @user25064 `RHS=Self` is not a trait bound, it is a default type.

Comment: I realized that shortly after I typed it, still, don't think that you can use a type that is not `Self`in `PartialEq`

Comment: @user25064 It's perfectly possible. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8a740751f0c7a79144d2b6fd2ddc5167&version=stable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many integral types, in Rust:

- `i8`, `i16`, `i32`, `i64` and `i128`,
- `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64` and `u128`,
- `isize`,
- `usize`.

In some cases, mixed arithmetic or comparisons would have an obvious implementation as a lossless conversion is possible in one direction:

- `i<x>` can always be converted to `i<y>` if `x < y`,
- `u<x>` can always be converted to `u<y>` if `x < y`,
- `u<x>` can always be converted to `i<y>` if `x < y`.

Some conversions, however, are not obvious or not portable:

- `i<x>` cannot be converted to `u<y>` no matter what the respective values of `x` and `y` are,
- `isize` and `usize` have a platform specific size anywhere, as small as 16 bits but as large as 64 bits.

Therefore, since Rust is not keen on overflows or underflows, it is unlikely that *arbitrary* mixed arithmetic or comparisons will ever be implemented.

A restricted subset could be implemented, but then two questions are raised:

- isn't a restricted subset unergonomic?
- isn't using mixed types a sign of design issue? In the same vein that quantities should have units, quantities should probably have a *known magnitude*.

Comment: I guess overflows and underflows will never occur during a comparison, if it's properly implemented. Also, Rust already allows the use of mixed types by allowing the implementation of `PartialEq<T>` for `U`. I just think it could provide a standard implementation of it for integers, as I'm forbid to implement existing traits for existing types.

Comment: @Milack27 Although we can say that such implementations are possible, it is more important to understand whether we really want that. The last bullet point in the answer raises the culprit: _"isn't using mixed types a sign of design issue?"_

Comment: @E_net4 Oh sorry, now I got it! I thought _design issue_ was refering to the language, not to an application. Yes, I think there's space for discussion, here. Still, my opinion remains. If the mixed types should be used or not, it's up to the programmer. In case they decide to use mixed types, the language should give full support.

Comment: @Milack27 That also depends on what you call "full support". How would you compare an `i64` with a `u64`? In C++, such a comparison, although not UB, could just yield an unexpected result in certain edge cases. And not everyone feels OK with the compiler introducing some complex logic for just an integer comparison.

Comment: I, for one, am definitely not okay in having complex logic in `==` between integers; I'd rather have a compiler error pointing out I am doing something fishy than a tiny performance penalty here and there.

Comment: @E_net4 Check if the `i64` is smaller than zero. Otherwise convert it to `u64` and proceed with a normal comparison.

Comment: @CodesInChaos IMO that is too much for an operation that would typically translate to one comparison machine instruction. This should be enough to understand that there is no clear cut on how Rust should behave.

Comment: @E_net4 I think that providing a comparison logic between an `i64` and an `u64` is better than forcing the programmer to use a cast and have an unexpected result, just like it happens in C++. But if you are not OK with the overhead, you can use the cast, anyway.

Comment: @Milack27 I disagree, but we have extended this discussion for too long here.

Comment: @Milack27: Custom comparison logic makes vectorization more complicated. Rust has traditionally stood on the side of making costs explicit (even small costs) and throwing your mistakes in your face (rather than silently fixing them for you with magic). It may change, but it's the statu quo :)

Answer (score 9):

It is expected behaviour - Rust is a strongly typed language and it doesn't perform implicit casts between integers of different types.

I don't think this will ever change in the future, as it would be a potential source of bugs that are notoriously difficult to find.

You need to be explicit and watch out for [potential caveats of numeric casts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/casting-between-types.html#numeric-casts) (truncation etc.):

```
let x: i32 = 4;
let y: i16 = 4;

println!("{}", x == y as i32);
```

Comment: It makes sense, but I don't think there's an implicit cast here. We're just comparing two values as they are. I think using the `as` operator could be much worse. For example, `let a: u8 = 255;` and `let b: i8 = -1`. We could safely say that `a != b` and even that `a > b` if `PartialEq` and `PartialOrd` were implemented between these types. However, `a == b as u8`.

Comment: @Milack27: In order to compare the value, the comparison implementation *will* have to perform a cast. At the CPU level, two integers can only be compared if they have the same bitwidth, and the comparison on the bits only make sense if both are signed or both are unsigned. It is less error-prone to implement it once, but it will occur.

Comment: @Milack27 if you wanted to compare `u8` with `i8` you would still need to have some common ground to do this; the difference might be obvious for a human, but this sort of operation is done on the binary level.

Comment: I understand. Nevertheless, the language itself could have a logic that checks if both `a` and `b` are within the overlapped range [0, 127]. If they are, the cast can be done safely, and the comparison follows naturally. Otherwise, it's assumed that `a > b`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I submitted [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3354) and, among out a host of misguided answers, thomcc provided this valuable comment:

> I think the inference issues make this a non-starter. I'd expect this to break all the rust code where a variable of numeric type is compared against a number literal (for example, a == 0). We had a similar (but less extreme) issue in std::simd, and it broke a ton of code (even things that didn't care at all about simd).
>
> > Type inference shouldn't be affected by this change, because the generic parameter on PartialOrd and PartialEq is defaulted to Self. Therefore, expressions like 1 == 1_u8 will continue to work by correctly inferring the first literal to be a u8.
>
> Sadly, I don't believe this is how type inference works, at least not at the moment (and my understanding is that extending it to handle defaults the way some folks expect requires some nontrivial design work, at the very least).

So, this is the real answer why integers of different types cannot be compared

---

I researched and found a couple arguments. Comparing differently sized integers...

1. requires implicit casts, which can easily be misused and cause bugs
2. is hard to define properly / can yield unexpected results in edge cases
3. requires non-trivial logic (e.g. sign checks or zero extension) and may have unacceptable performance implications for an integral type operation
4. may hint at a design problem in the code
5. adding (Partial)Eq/Ord implementations for each combination of all 12 integer types is 264 implementations, which may impact compile-times

Responses:

1. is moot: there would be explicit Eq/Ord implementations for differently sized integers.
2. is also moot, since the mathematical definition of ordering is well-defined and intuitive.
3. can be tested with [a benchmark](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a8704dfd953be0d0e750b2d916ccc7f). On my Intel i5-8600k, the `u64 < i64` check with a sign check runs 0.1 nanoseconds slower than the native `u64 < u64` check, which is negligible.
4. may be valid, albeit very subjective and hard to proove.
5. this could be tested, although I don't believe it will be a problem:

   - the standard library is pre-compiled
   - there are thousands of trait implementations in the standard library already (e.g. [422 on u8 alone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u8.html#trait-implementations)
   - there's precedent for trait implementations on combinations of integer types: From, TryFrom, Shl(Assign), Shr(Assign)

From the arguments I could find, I currently believe allowing comparing differently sized integers is a net positive for Rust.

The algorithms have already been implemented by orlp in the [num-ord crate](https://crates.io/crates/num-ord)